# change IP when a CNAME is used

Tags: networking, dns, alias, hosts-file, cname

I want to set 96.7.41.139 as IP address of download.microsoft.com
I checked this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot
and set hosts as below.

```
96.7.41.139 main.dl.ms.akadns.net
96.7.41.139 a767.dscms.akamai.net
96.7.41.139 download.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
96.7.41.139 download.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net
96.7.41.139 download.microsoft.com
```

but didn't succeed.
The result is below.  What should I do?

```
C:\Users\admin>nslookup download.microsoft.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.16.17.4

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    a767.dscms.akamai.net
Addresses:  2a00:1e48:1:4::bc2b:484a
          2a00:1e48:1:4::bc2b:4852
          2a00:1e48:1:4::bc2b:4870
          188.43.72.74
          188.43.72.112
          188.43.72.82
Aliases:  download.microsoft.com
          download.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
          main.dl.ms.akadns.net
          download.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net


C:\Users\admin>ping download.microsoft.com

Pinging a767.dscms.akamai.net [188.43.72.74] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 188.43.72.74: bytes=32 time=211ms TTL=43

-----
C:\Users\admin>ping download.microsoft.com.nsatc.net

Pinging download.microsoft.com.nsatc.net [96.7.41.139] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=358ms TTL=37
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=346ms TTL=37

-------
C:\Users\admin>ping main.dl.ms.akadns.net

Pinging main.dl.ms.akadns.net [96.7.41.139] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=334ms TTL=37
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=357ms TTL=37

-----
C:\Users\admin>ping download.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net

Pinging download.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net [96.7.41.139] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=37
Reply from 96.7.41.139: bytes=32 time=291ms TTL=37
```

Comment: Have you rebooted since changing your hosts file? Also, I think `nslookup` always makes a DNS query instead of checking the hosts file, but I'm not certain. `ping` is a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to lack of reps..
Though, adding to user Xyon's answer, instead of restart, you can try 
IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS 
to clear any IP address mappings already in the cache.
You may need to do this a few times to clear the cache.

Hope this helps.